# InnoSetup: "The volume for a file has been externally altered"

Tags: inno-setup

InnoSetup appears to be corrupting my executable when compiling the setup project.
Executing the source file works fine, but executing the file after installation produces Win32  error 1006 "The volume for a file has been externally altered".

I've tried disabling compression and setting various flags, to no avail.

Has anyone experienced this?

**UPDATE**

Okay there's been some twists to the situation:

At the moment, I can even manually copy a working file to the location it is installed to and get "The volume for a file...". To be clear: I uninstall the application, create the same folder and paste the files there and run.

**UPDATE 2**

Some more details for those that want it:
The InnoSetup script is compiled by FinalBuilder using output from msbuild, also executed by FinalBuilder, running on my machine with XP SP3. The executable is a C# .Net assembly compiled in configuration Release|AnyCPU. The file works when executed in the folder the Install Script takes it from. It produces the same behaviour on an XP Virtual Machine. The MD5 hashes of the source file and the installed file are the same.

Comment: Just to be sure, this happens if you create a new installer to put just this file without modifiers in the target system? 
It happens on any machine you install the file? it happens if you just copy the file? what's the exact [FILES] directive you're using to include the file? are you executing any PascalScript at installation time?

Comment: Thanks for the interest everyone. I got a working install by making a new ISS file with just the minimum entries (AppName, AppVer + files). I'm now working on adding the rest of the requirements line by line and testing as I go.

Comment: I'm now getting the same problem again and it is driving me up the wall. Help!

Comment: @Andre please post the log of the install, and/or the script you are using the produce the install.    This will help in identifying why you might have the problem...   If you are improperly installing any Microsoft Code you can get this error

Comment: Hi Robert. At the moment it looks as if that specific location on my computer is "bad". I'm still trying to figure out how extensive that is.

Comment: @Andre - Sounds like it's time to run a ChkDsk

Comment: I've run ChkDsk, no joy.

Comment: @Andre - I got exactly the same problem and it's making my system just about unusable. Because the "bad" location is the powershell.exe. Have you found a solution / workaround??

Comment: @GarethOwen I wish I could give you better news, but I couldn't get a reliable fix. I ended up using NSIS (Nullsoft Install system) instead. I'm not even convinced that it was InnoSetup. What is touching your powershell.exe?

Comment: Thinking back on it, this was really a painful problem. I would get drastic - copy powershell.exe somewhere else and run there, or rename a different executable on your system that works to "powershell.exe" and see what happens. A cold restart?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! If I rename powershell.exe, or move it, it works fine. But we have some batch scripts which directly reference "powershell.exe". I'm going to try changing the PATH settings in my system to reference a copy of the powershell folder.

Comment: hmm... it seems any file on my system with the name powershell.exe gives the same error message. No matter where it is located. So if I rename notepad.exe and double click it, I get the 'externally altered' error. This is ridiculous!

Answer (score 20):

Ok, I just received this same error. I have a config which my executable uses. I looked in my folder a million times - but finally notice the config file was zero length. I corrected the config and the error stopped occurring.

Check the simplest things first... good lucK!

Comment: Unfortunately I've moved on so I can't validate your answer, but it might help someone, glad you got it sorted.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me get powershell working again. A 0kb powershell.exe.config was giving me the exact same error message!

Comment: I got the same error message in a custom developed .NET application. It turned out the harddrive was full so the *.exe.config file could not be saved properly and was empty.

Comment: We had this with Varonis console - in our case deleted the 0-size config file, then the product launched and asked a few configuration questions to get going again.

Comment: Works for me also.

Comment: I faced the same issue when my D drive was full. Turns out executable's config was corrupted because of this and became 0 bytes long. This answer helped me catch it!

Answer (score 3):

> ERROR_FILE_INVALID
>   1006 (0x3EE): The volume for a file has been externally altered so that the opened file is no longer valid.

I suspect you're having this issue after moving the files to a network share. It seems to me that what's happening is you have an open file-handle - possibly to a temporary file you are creating - and then some other process (perhaps running on a different host) is coming along and renaming or deleting that file or its' parent directory tree.

So my advice is:

1. Try installing to a local directory
2. Run after an anti-virus scan, in
   safe-mode or on a different machine
   to see if there isn't some
   background nasty changing
   volume/directory properties while
   your program is running.
3. Make sure the program itself isn't doing anything weird with the volume or directory tree you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

Never seen that before.  I've got a few questions and suggestions:
- Are you signing the EXE during the compile of the setup?  If so, try leaving that part out. 
- WHat OS are you installing on or does it happen on all machines you've tried?
- Run the install with the /LOG="c:\install.log" option and post the log.  It might show something happening during install. 
- Run a byte compare or MD5 check on the source EXE and the installed EXE.  Are they the same?  Do they have the same version resource?